# 400: BadRequest with .Net Mass Downloader 1.5.0.1

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

Has anybody else had trouble with getting the .Net Framework source code?  Google doesn't have anything to say about this error message, and neither does the CodePlex issue tracker.

Here is the command I'm using to get the source code for the modules that make up mscorlib.dll.  Am I doing something obviously wrong?

NetMassDownloader.exe -o source -f "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll"

Comment: I have not gotten this working since the day everyone reported it no longer working.

Answer (score 1):

The 400 Bad Request error is an HTTP status code that means that the request you sent to the website server was somehow malformed therefore the server was unable to understand or process the request.

Resolution

1. Check for errors in the URL. The most common reason for a 400 Bad Request error is because the URL was typed wrong or the link that was clicked on points to a URL with some kind of mistake in it.
2. Though it's rare, the 400 Bad Request error could be an issue with the web site's server that you are trying to access.

Answer (score 1):

Download it in another computer and copy/paste that folder to your own computer. I've got a similar problem with the tool, and that was my workaround.